# Laravel 8: How to list data on blade with foreach() loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show some data on blade by a foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach($topAnswered as $topAns)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <h3 class="h5 mb-0"><a href="{{ route('show.question', $topAns->slug) }}" class="text-uppercase">{{ $topAns->title }}</a></h3>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <div>{{ $topAns->answers->count() }}</div>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <div>{{ $topAns->likes->count() }}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But I need to retrieve these data descending based on `$topAns->likes->count()`. So how can I add this condition to the `foreach()` loop.

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to make sure it is already ordered before looping, usually in the controller.

Comment: Can you show us you controller code?

Comment: If you add your code that fetched the collection `$topAnswered` we can do the ordering there.

Comment: @Ruub `$topAnswered = Question::withCount('answers')->having('answers_count', '>', 0)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method sortBy for collections, [learn more here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby)

```php
@foreach($topAnswered->sortBy(function($answer, $key){return $answer->likes->count();}) as $topAns)
...
@endforeach
```

Some advices:

- I think you should do this sorting on the controller, so in the blade file it is already sorted
- On your controller you should eager load the likes so it doesn't make a new query for every *likes* relationship, `->with('likes')`
- You also can load `->withCount('likes')` and sort by `likes_count`

[learn more about relationships and eager loading here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: To add a little more to this answer, you must always sort this type of data on the controller, if you can let the database do so, it will do it in 1% the time it would take to PHP/Laravel do it in a collection, so always try to do it in the DB and then if you need more sorting or moving around, use the collection for the final touch, so that way is the most performant one.